# Finding files by only knowing extension?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-extension

I'm somewhat disorganized in my file saving habits, so I wind up using the Search function in Windows Explorer more often than one should. I was wondering, is it possible to have Windows find all files of a certain extension ( like, say for example all .rar files) if it is, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open up Windows Explorer.
- Go to `C:\`
- Type in `*.rar` into the search box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then wait for the search process to find all the rar-files on your C-drive.

EDIT:

`*` is a wildcard, so you can also do more advanced things with it. Suppose you know your file is called `<something>final.<extension>` you can search for `*final.*` to find all files, whose names (excluding extension) ends in `final` or you can type `kind:` or `size:` into the search field to search by kind of file or size of file.

Comment: It seems to search for contents of file. This makes it slow. And most of the output data may be irrelevant. For faster search, there would be a way to just look at file names.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for `ext:".rar"` will list all `.rar` files. (unlike `*.rar`, which actually searches for `*rar*`).

---

Demo:

Searching for `ext:".rar"` will all list `.rar` files and nothing else:

[image]

Searching for  `*.rar`, which actually searches for `*rar*`:

[image]

Comment: Note that this can be combined with a search by name, e.g. `ext:".rar" blah` will find only `.rar` files with "blah" somewhere in the name, while `*blah*.rar` will also find `blah.rar2`